# Terraform file path is not being resolved when using {path.cwd}

Tags: terraform

I have been trying to fix what seems to be a path resolving issue while running `Terraform`. The issue I notice is, the `${path.cwd}` is resolving to `/terraform` path  and not the actual path in which the `.tf` files and the `output.tf` files exist. I have tried hardcoding the path, but, what I see error related to the file not being available in that path as well. How to list out all the files in `path.cwd` to help with debugging if it is possible? What could be causing this?

```
output {
   value = templatefile {
      "${path.cwd}/somefile.yml" {
         x = a.b.c.something.id,
         y = c.v.b.something.id
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a Linux/Unix or Windows system? Also, make sure there is not a typo in the file name in both places, i.e., the `templatefile` function call and on the filesystem.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your code. I am not able to reproduce the error (Tried in Linux and Windows).

Comment: `path.cwd` is the directory where you ran Terraform CLI, which isn't necessarily the directory containing your `.tf` files. `path.module` is the typical way to refer to the directory containing your current module's `.tf` files. Does it work better if you replace `path.cwd` with `path.module`?

Comment: Great! It's hard to guess from just what you shared why `path.cwd` didn't work, but possible answers are that this output value exists in a different module than the root module (so it's directory is different) _or_ that you ran Terraform with its `-chdir` option to select a different root directory in which case `path.cwd` would reflect the _original_ directory, before switching.